# Do I need to create an Index manually when setting up a foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, ddl

I have these schema in my SQL Server database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] 
(
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [Text]         NVARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId]   INT              DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_PhrasePhraseCategory] 
         FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryId]) 
         REFERENCES [dbo].[PhraseCategory] ([PhraseCategoryShortId])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PhraseCategory] 
(
    [PhraseCategoryId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [PhraseCategoryShortId] INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]                  VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseCategoryShortId] ASC)
);
```

Am I correct in saying that if I go to the `PhraseCategory` table and try to delete a row it will check to see if that `PhraseCategoryShortId` is used in the phrase table? If that's a case then should I index `CategoryId` in that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes. This foreign key establishes a constraints such that a `Phrase` must have a valid `PhraseCategory`. When a category is deleted, the `PhraseCategory` is deleted, the `Phrase` table is checked to validate that no "orphan" `Phrase`s are left.

While a foreign key must always refer to a unique value (either via an explicit constraint or a primary key), the **referring** field does not have to be index, so you'll need to index it yourself if you care about the performance of a delete operation on `PhraseCategory`.